# Output contains less elements than expected

Tags: java, arrays

I'm learning Java on my own and just learned to declare, initialize and print from arrays. I have tried this exercise [Basic Arrays](https://programmingbydoing.com/a/basic-arrays-3.html) that I found online for practice.

Here is my code:

```
public class ArrayExerciseTwo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] values = new int[1000];

        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            values[i] = (10 + (int)(Math.random() * 89));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            // at every 20 elements, print newline
            else if (i % 21 == 0) {
                System.out.println("");
            }

            // otherwise print 2 spaces
            else {
                System.out.print(values[i] + "  ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

61  58  95  56  46  63  31  84  76  93  33  87  12  32  69  93  32  95  52  67
93  59  80  23  15  80  91  51  72  90  75  38  15  86  59  67  44  53  93  26
84  34  50  10  17  55  29  26  80  66  53  76  26  76  31  80  17  20  44  23
16  52  22  79  55  49  83  44  69  95  61  14  93  50  42  88  66  59  65  26
43  84  19  30  82  68  85  25  81  67  61  64  60  18  44  25  53  77  29  14
24  59  48  57  69  23  59  65  71  86  77  71  44  47  40  51  56  51  62  20
91  75  94  61  42  76  58  48  18  32  46  51  12  66  57  14  33  98  58  39
50  40  36  56  74  71  38  64  52  77  45  61  21  85  77  89  57  67  93  18
80  14  97  30  26  81  33  62  78  77  46  58  17  38  80  77  82  56  67  75
66  46  79  72  66  46  88  56  13  69  39  88  56  82  48  87  94  66  57  15
92  46  58  52  68  17  36  98  38  47  56  10  55  36  69  69  64  48  38  24
89  90  10  19  10  66  13  30  52  68  32  96  54  66  69  88  33  23  10  72
78  94  81  48  44  67  72  51  58  70  47  16  41  79  29  57  47  38  55  72
24  97  44  11  64  17  81  72  63  43  94  22  37  91  86  19  79  88  69  33
55  73  44  31  15  90  65  95  13  58  79  80  64  18  12  95  53  43  60  16
56  94  34  30  29  91  19  15  14  60  51  59  26  46  14  26  17  83  74  19
19  50  16  68  69  71  10  33  90  81  38  51  13  63  30  46  36  16  94  21
20  72  42  91  61  16  18  82  76  81  82  49  48  82  94  10  79  50  18  85
47  98  51  18  21  21  92  45  27  44  77  30  20  21  65  60  70  37  87  67
38  65  48  42  76  73  17  24  85  34  61  67  97  39  34  68  66  75  28  96
48  71  25  85  83  18  38  90  29  86  65  22  30  38  49  11  86  50  68  98
56  64  21  96  42  27  80  24  43  67  61  89  28  84  34  98  70  64  69  87
84  76  52  23  40  58  16  28  78  18  94  89  81  37  35  52  18  42  76  24
77  81  37  41  65  65  78  88  96  60  70  56  40  45  41  60  70  77  70  85
74  34  56  26  48  18  33  59  88  16  70  30  77  68  19  96  40  47  72  12
70  75  16  34  32  71  52  79  27  41  91  30  44  12  23  71  78  12  81  88
27  68  58  55  79  80  35  26  67  46  74  25  40  44  34  82  49  94  28  26
59  78  69  12  46  61  16  27  77  34  37  26  60  59  59  82  83  72  35  48
17  42  70  77  45  63  26  70  46  60  74  69  98  11  36  41  35  80  47  67
19  24  58  52  86  96  28  78  18  25  94  19  56  64  58  67  14  44  63  46
22  76  45  92  70  30  35  49  81  77  85  46  62  70  36  29  37  78  76  78
15  31  13  70  24  47  93  66  21  47  82  87  43  18  71  27  96  26  91  69
32  65  47  29  49  64  37  69  38  26  67  21  17  82  59  55  29  22  68  42
19  47  54  75  15  62  43  95  50  77  28  85  82  80  62  32  10  35  31  27
94  83  14  77  83  66  54  60  77  81  68  23  82  86  80  94  87  51  31  88
85  41  40  14  54  72  42  12  15  94  67  76  47  46  70  88  64  94  54  46
12  15  84  74  10  58  43  18  10  12  56  21  71  75  10  49  38  91  71  40
89  62  17  60  45  27  76  79  96  21  87  67  17  62  87  21  63  87  87  50
75  57  17  77  46  45  44  70  10  54  81  88  60  42  59  96  77  93  55  63
67  23  74  31  84  92  96  13  32  24  51  25  18  37  84  73  72  47  33  64
73  75  43  98  83  45  79  44  82  54  11  80  19  23  17  37  41  46  21  92
24  52  66  29  65  16  38  84  83  78  57  62  21  60  82  28  43  72  52  72
80  67  34  85  82  95  19  69  90  53  96  18  47  44  63  88  61  30  94  44
25  15  92  22  17  31  45  42  94  95  98  41  56  34  54  11  38  38  74  82
75  82  79  73  23  64  77  24  18  40  42  29  97  23  43  96  65  19  53  37
91  32  12  38  23  98  15  55  45  51  46  21  92  47  25  83  44  38  54  23
67  86  21  19  85  38  10  85  47  53  80  53  63  65  42  63  78  50  89  21
50  37  32  66  80  40  97  24  54  28  76  31

My output should display 1000 elements (20 columns x 50 rows) since this would total to 1000 elements. However, I am only getting 992 elements (the last 8 are missing). I increased the array size to 1008 but that doesn't seem like the right solution to the problem.

Comment: How can I learn to use a debugger when I am just a beginner learning arrays? I didn't mean to learn about a debugger. I meant to learn about this specific problem with my code.

Comment: Why are you complaining about learning to use a necessary and valuable tool, one that will help you immensely not with just this code but also with future code? Ridiculous.

Comment: With all due respect, I am not complaining. I didn't post this to be spoonfed a solution for some homework like many people that post. I am actually trying to learn and have struggled with different solutions with this problem for a few hours, as a beginner would. However, asking for help here is a burden, I guess. I'll just delete my post and not learn. Discouraging.

Comment: The solution is correct -- learn the debugging techniques to first isolate the problem, something you haven't yet done. Encouraging.

Comment: Much better! A hint of guidance! Now that I have some sort of direction, I can act. Thank you.

Comment: I've reopened because it wasn't a duplicate of that other question and because you've met all the usual requirements (your code compiles, plus you've given both the expected output and the actual output). I don't disagree that you should definitely learn how to use a debugger. However another way to see what's going on here is to fill the array with numbers `0`, `1`, `2`, ... rather than random numbers. That way you'll see easily which ones aren't being printed.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] values = new int[1000];

        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            values[i] = (10 + (int) (Math.random() * 89));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            if (i % 20 == 0) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    printit(i, values);
                } else {
                    System.out.println();
                    printit(i, values);
                }
            } else
                System.out.print(values[i] + "  ");
        }
    }

    public static void printit(int i, int[] values) {
        System.out.print(values[i] + "  ");
    }
}
```

I got it! Before, I was not printing the number at the index when i % 20 == 0. I was simply moving to the next index. That's why my output was missing elements.

Output

94  82  16  11  64  16  34  13  93  47  78  83  11  55  67  10  50  96  62  94
95  83  65  17  67  78  62  29  44  74  57  65  21  20  67  35  24  94  89  94
16  91  42  92  65  26  72  55  33  59  82  40  45  86  89  17  60  78  28  44
86  81  26  92  85  93  13  32  83  51  88  83  26  32  42  17  11  93  61  37
34  79  17  49  54  23  66  38  88  91  55  70  35  98  94  43  22  39  70  57
53  17  42  86  95  11  90  72  15  64  80  92  63  18  85  96  75  46  85  34
56  71  92  38  85  14  58  80  86  71  82  11  22  88  48  66  22  60  59  67
65  18  20  55  29  41  28  58  40  35  28  97  45  48  39  22  29  23  93  28
35  86  74  23  78  34  18  50  85  39  13  61  18  12  18  21  73  11  27  18
45  23  22  45  73  77  10  15  26  71  95  46  17  59  19  55  68  91  60  88
12  32  27  63  20  82  85  51  42  72  42  55  27  30  27  24  61  17  74  80
54  44  33  71  52  10  80  58  76  86  65  64  27  49  38  13  63  90  18  70
48  95  62  62  80  82  66  57  91  56  22  83  16  76  48  85  66  84  71  68
44  14  49  55  47  31  62  62  14  28  45  57  70  37  18  23  82  88  32  62
53  90  46  68  40  60  49  51  43  33  96  52  35  93  54  95  59  40  83  70
98  89  78  80  29  53  85  55  62  86  53  66  40  24  13  33  90  87  33  45
18  49  54  45  73  50  79  46  72  38  59  12  84  43  46  85  55  97  13  19
48  74  80  93  43  90  16  84  49  12  81  59  91  23  57  43  92  27  37  25
12  34  24  58  81  58  72  64  71  84  95  46  31  33  25  70  28  32  46  79
83  16  15  86  21  68  67  95  92  81  84  59  66  85  51  45  32  32  63  65
20  64  12  21  41  69  18  20  34  93  52  89  55  43  55  61  85  92  92  62
42  70  79  24  88  49  50  46  25  19  14  51  24  74  19  60  59  38  56  15
29  63  15  86  29  53  80  79  95  93  47  22  80  94  53  47  84  64  34  61
95  44  84  44  33  93  18  42  53  84  35  58  52  47  52  11  78  32  62  20
34  47  80  72  15  61  72  50  12  86  52  13  47  40  62  26  27  21  72  38
24  45  73  79  23  93  89  34  34  27  81  80  94  71  39  64  16  84  33  22
45  58  56  15  14  70  16  39  68  40  56  66  85  36  45  45  18  23  12  44
54  21  96  89  24  83  13  78  72  97  16  47  62  18  60  52  59  33  76  42
16  14  43  36  18  74  41  81  39  81  93  45  56  11  87  84  14  14  24  24
11  25  40  89  41  56  46  32  63  25  53  57  61  68  84  74  18  87  42  94
61  15  30  45  62  17  54  23  88  47  84  67  77  71  12  62  44  15  79  39
83  91  68  68  45  37  16  75  34  26  55  32  26  31  43  54  38  29  26  53
49  69  10  11  95  36  63  18  29  25  81  79  23  90  46  34  39  88  88  68
17  94  18  82  30  11  42  11  12  59  10  88  77  44  68  31  11  98  94  87
55  79  80  16  29  28  24  12  62  37  12  78  19  17  71  81  82  66  62  10
48  42  48  30  96  51  30  16  80  89  68  78  57  68  31  77  32  60  49  36
83  14  82  96  43  28  53  30  78  63  93  95  53  24  35  19  60  66  38  79
20  48  48  91  85  27  14  34  10  65  86  15  46  87  86  69  95  93  91  85
50  49  27  81  60  16  82  73  75  51  62  31  55  80  87  76  43  43  13  15
14  45  48  17  14  90  26  98  79  48  50  42  87  87  69  16  82  51  25  27
19  51  10  23  17  62  44  39  60  93  73  91  36  14  20  31  55  91  56  24
72  31  76  87  14  13  14  51  84  81  14  16  63  56  30  69  79  80  48  97
92  87  31  63  76  89  58  26  72  81  88  24  87  36  94  60  67  26  59  57
59  78  59  17  70  54  37  19  83  89  10  10  74  18  75  70  57  61  19  29
95  42  44  71  33  34  38  69  79  48  36  66  42  66  48  23  73  24  70  14
47  43  38  85  96  53  72  66  24  65  30  48  64  44  34  33  59  20  12  68
28  91  90  27  56  87  46  66  70  39  32  63  73  41  82  42  74  11  87  28
14  27  88  18  77  83  34  71  23  86  39  69  62  17  47  25  80  12  88  86
15  34  93  92  96  57  42  46  50  32  18  10  33  11  40  34  39  47  23  73
58  69  85  29  27  37  42  83  38  85  82  85  16  43  36  14  16  44  75  67

Comment: While it is now working the way you want you might still want to look at the contents of the main loop and consider how you can tighten it up/eliminate redundancy (which will have the benevolent side-effect of making it more readable to others and to your future self).

Comment: By redundancy, do you mean I should call the function in the outer else statement? Or?? Please explain. That's a helpful point I would like to improve upon.

Comment: For example, if you think more about how you might restructure the contents of the loop you will find you need only have one call to `printit()` instead of the essentially three calls to it you currently have.